# сравнение ключей двух словарей

Tags: python, словари

есть два словаря в каждом пары ключ значения(ключ= время значения массив из 18 чисел).изначально ключи представляют одну и ту же временную шкалу за исключением первая обладает мелким интервалом чем вторая.(первый словарь

```
{00:[0214,3426,4747,365],02:[21,234,1623,32],04:[20,2352,4325,351],06:[32384,3262,346,436],08:[32,42,2415,50],10:[132,841,251,743]}
```

второй словарь

```
{00:[432,3525,373,36],10[032;3213,235,65]
```

и при совпадении их прикидывать значения второго в первых в каждый ключ первого.думаю про ордер дикт но решение так и не созрело искренне прошу помощи

Comment: на каком языке у вас код? В Питоне, вы SyntaxError получите.

Comment: что вы хотите сделать: интерполяцию (взять разреженные данные и  посчитать приближённые значения для более мелкого интервала) или хотите собрать данные (по некой зависящей от задачи формуле) и из более мелких интервалов, крупные получить (некую статистику посчитать)?

Comment: так как в моем решении я все храню в модели которая представляет из себя словарь то я собираюсь сначала сделать определенное количество ключей с массивами углов, далее от этого интервала прокинуть значения дальше у меня есть 9 интервалов то самого маленького до крупного   .я хочу с больших интервалов брать ключи которых пересекаются с малым интервалом а между ними малые ключи пробрасывать массив с большего интервала(надеюсь тут нибудь что то понял)